# How to layout 2 textviews in a custom compound constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to give two Textviews the correct position in the Constraintlayout in my layout file. The problem is the textviews needs to be scalable using app: `autoSizeTextType="uniform"`. To make them scale I also have to match_parent on the `layout_width` and `layout_height`. This makes the two textviews overlap. How can I accomplish the desired result?

Current XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.362" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Actual result:

Both textviews scales, but overlaps, and are placed in the center of the constraintlayout.
The current state:
[image: The current state]

The expected result:

One textview centered in the middle. One textview aligned at the bottom. Both textviews scales with the constraintlayout.
Expected result: (3 different custom compounds in an activity) 
[image: Expected result]

Comment: you need to use fixed height for textview and not match_parent for auto sizing to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give top and bottom proper constraint

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#4689C8"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:textColor="#4689C8"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That works like a charm! The only thing that is missing is that the textview on the bottom should be smaller than the one above. How can i accomplish that? Like 75/25 or 60/30 and so on....

Comment: Nvm. this was fixed using the autoSizeStepGranulairty! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Textview size we have to add**

Answer (score 1):

Modify the TextView to have height and width of 0dp, this will match parent constraint view, add in a constraint for the views in relation to each other and that should give you as you asked for

```
<TextView

        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#4689C8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```